# ffmpeg error: at least one output file must be specified

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm trying to input this command to extract a video into frames:

`ffmpeg -i mirai.mpg -r 30 -t 2 -ss 0:00 -f image2_4%dpng`

But I keep getting this error: "At least one output file must be specified". I'm new to this, any help would be appreciated.

**UPDATE**

Solved, I removed the -f like you said. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It should work if you remove `-f` from your command line.  Try this:

```
ffmpeg -i mirai.mpg -r 30 -t 2 -ss 0:00 image2_4.png
```

Comment: Now it says: `[image2 @ 0x7fd3b1003c00] Could not get frame filename number 2 from pattern 'image2_4.png' (either set updatefirst or use a pattern like %03d within the filename pattern)
av_interleaved_write_frame(): Invalid argument` and then Conversion failed!

Comment: ffmpeg often spits out many misleading errors and warnings.  If you take a look, you will notice that a file named `image2_4.png` now exists and it has the frame that you have requested.

Comment: Your example has several issues. `-t 2` (duration of 2 seconds) makes no sense when outputting a single image: use `-frames:v 1` instead. `-ss 0:00` does nothing. Adding `-r` will change the frame rate and this is usually not desired when outputting images because `ffmpeg` may duplicate or drop images to match the declared `-r`. The user wanted to "extract a video into frames", but your example just creates one.

Comment: you're right.  the only point that I was expressing is that the `-f` needed to be removed.  I agree with you and your answer is better than mine.

Comment: Perhaps it would be best for the error message to be made more clear and for it to fail instead of outputting the image.

Answer (score 3):

## Output a series of images

This is the correct method:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mpg output_%03d.png
```

This will result in a numbered series of images such as:

```
output_001.png
output_002.png
output_003.png
...
```

- You do not need `-ss` (seek to specific position) if the value is going to be `0`.
- You do not need `-r` unless you want `ffmpeg` to duplicate or drop frames to match your desired frame rate (if it differs from the input frame rate).
- `-f image2` is superfluous unless used in a script where the output name uses a variable.

## Output a single image

Example to skip 30 seconds and output one image:

```
ffmpeg -ss 30 -i input -frames:v 1 output.png
```

See the [image file muxer documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#image2-2) for more info.